How do I use bootstrap to automatically increase font size on larger screens?
I'm trying to display bullet points on a screen with bootstrap and of course on my laptop the sizing is perfect, but when I try to display this onto a large TV screen or use the responsive tool in the browser, the fonts are not automatically increasing in size as I thought they would using bootstrap's Display 1 where they specifically note that the font should resize automatically.
Is there a way to do this using only bootstrap or is custom CSS required to auto-size the font as different screen breakpoints are met?
This is what I've tried:
`<body>
<div class="container-fluid vh-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col justify-content-start mx-3">
            {% for point in bullet_points %}
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <h1 class="display-1 fw-bold">
                        {{ point }}
                    </h1>
                </div>
                    {% endfor %} 
        </div>        
        <div class="col w-50 vh-100">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end vh-100">
                <img src="{% static 'images/background.png' %}" clas="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>

`

Looks to be working for me, using the following, when i run the snippet the text is smaller than when I expand the snippet to full page:


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid vh-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col justify-content-start mx-3">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <h1 class="display-1 fw-bold">
                        Some Text To Display
                    </h1>
                </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>



